# How can I pass a variable from a template to header.php of a theme

Tags: templates, headers

As of version 5.5.0, WordPress introduced second argument (array $args) to get_header.

I am calling get_header in my templates including index.php and I want to pass meta description value from template to header.php

And I am trying this

```php
$args = array('Index meta desc');
get_header(null, $args);
```

While in header.php file the value of $args is an empty array.

Not sure, if I am calling the variable correctly.

Any comment/answer will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: the canonically correct answer would be "you don't". E.g. if you're outputting a meta description it's better to do that on the `wp_head` hook/action, or in `header.php`. Or better yet, load a custom header, e.g. `get_header('mytemplate')` which loads `header-mytemplate.php`. Otherwise it appears that you've asked how to implement a solution, not how to solve your problem. You should have asked _"How do I add a meta tag to the header of a page with a custom template?"_

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell Thank you for the response.
I don't a want custom header for each template as there can be so many templates.

Yes, you're right, that's what I need adding a meta tag to the header with a custom template. 
Will check that hook. Thanks.